# Slideshow changing size depending on image

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images in a slideshow inside a div that looks like a "polaroid". Turns out one of the images makes the whole polaroid longer. I don't want this to happen, I want it to always remain the same size.
Here's my html:

```
     <div class="polaroid">       
      <div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px">
          <img class="mySlides" src="<c:url value="/resources/pics/casa1.jpg" />" >
          <img class="mySlides" src="<c:url value="/resources/pics/casa2.jpg" />" >
          <img class="mySlides" src="<c:url value="/resources/pics/casa3.jpg" />" >
          <img class="mySlides" src="<c:url value="/resources/pics/casa4.jpg" />" >
          <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
            <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
            <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
            <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(4)"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="container">
        <p class="direction">Street Name, Los Angeles, CA</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.polaroid {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.mySlides{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's how my polaroid looks

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is an option for you, but you can use background images instead of src.  Then you can set that div to the size you want the image to be and use background-size:cover on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<img class="mySlides" src="<c:url value="/resources/pics/casa1.jpg" />" >
```

if you can use background image instead, you can do:

```
<div class="mySlide" style="background-image:url('dynamic-src-goes-here')"></div>
```

Then just set the css for mySlide:

```
.myslide{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

it will fill the width and height to fit, so it may not be exactly what you want, but perhaps it's a good compromise?

Comment: hmm not exactly, I've updated my question with an image of how the polaroid looks